# Using non-localized formulae in Excel automation

Tags: c++, excel, com, localization, office-automation

I've been playing around with basic Excel automation using the COM interface, mainly utilizing [`IDispatch::Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221479(v=vs.85).aspx).

My test involved adding a formula in a freshly created Excel document. Using a devised wrapper library, it looks like this:

```cpp
sheet.getObject( "Range", "A1" ).set( "Value", 23 );
sheet.getObject( "Range", "A2" ).set( "Value", 42 );
sheet.getObject( "Range", "A3" ).set( "Formula", "=SUMME(A1:A2)" ); // WTF?
```

Notice: I'm using the (german) localized formula name `SUMME` here, instead of the identifier `SUM` as expected. When doing the same with the macro recorder in Excel, the generated VBA code contains `SUM`. Using `SUM` in my C++ code, I end up with a `#NAME?` error in Excel.

Microsoft's [documentation for the `Range.FormulaLocal` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx) says the following:

> Returns or sets the formula for the object, using A1-style references
>   *in the language of the user*.

(emphasis was made by me).

So I hoped that using `Formula` instead of `FormulaLocal` I could get around these localization woes, but apparently this is not the case.

Is there any way I can use non localized formulae? I'd guess there's some well hidden setting.

Comment: Yes,it works for me. I´m using Excel in Spanish and the property formula is assigned with English names and it works. No hidden settings, but I remember that it didn´t work on older Excel versions (previous to 12, pretty old now).

Comment: @CarlosE.Ferro Does "12" mean Office 12 aka Office 2007? I'm using Excel 2010 here.

Comment: Yes, I told you it was pretty old. Excel 2007 has it working, so I don't know why it doesn't work on yours. Sorry :-(

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer to document what I've found out:

**Workaround for `Formula`**

To set the `Formula` property, there's ultimatively a call to `IDispatch::Invoke`, which was implemented as

```
object->Invoke(
    dispid,
    IID_NULL,
    LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT,  // <-- "locale context"
    DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT,
    &dispparams,
    NULL,
    &excepinfo,
    &argerr ) );
```

Changing `LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT` to `LOCALE_NEUTRAL` has the effect that the properties `Formula` and `FormulaLocal` start to behave differently. In my german localized Excel installation the two calls

```
sheet.getObject( "Range", "A3" ).set( "FormulaLocal", "=SUMME(A1:A2)" );
sheet.getObject( "Range", "B3" ).set( "Formula", "=SUM(A1:A2)" );
```

do the same thing now.

*Currently, this is not a real solution to my problem, as I usually expect things not working as documented to break silently behind my back*. Proof: `NumberFormat` and `NumberFormatLocal` still do the same thing (!), that means I'm required to use the localized date format codes (e.g. `"JJJJ-MM-TT"` for ISO 8601) with both properties.

**Workaround for `NumberFormat`**

To build the format string: Use the [Application.International Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840213.aspx).

Comment: Oh, I completely forget the LOCALE_ID (LCID) that goes in that call... we notched it to 0 long time ago. That's the reason it worked here and not in your installation.

Comment: @CarlosE.Ferro Thank you for the confirmation (and I can confirm that `LOCALE_NEUTRAL == 0` here). Did you deal with the `NumberFormat` as well?

Comment: No, we use Excel automation only for basic reporting, and we rarely set the cell format, except for some ranges where we apply old pre-defined table formats (XlClassic, for instance). 

But yes, for specific decimals, we build a string using zeros and excel.International(XlDecimalSeparator) and for dates, we build strings like 'mm-yyyy' and set them with numberFormat property